# Exchange between activity and a service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, binding

I have two activities and one service all in one app

activity2 will start and stop the service

activity1 is the main UI

the service have two supposed tasks:
1- receive data from a server though a socket and pass it to activity1 to update the user interface

2- receive data from activity1 and send it to the sever

the problem is i wasn't able to have a clear idea about how i can make the service exchange data with the activity

i read about AIDL , Binding here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

i couldn't apply it on my codes, even after three weeks of hard work i didn't get it !!!

thank you !

service:

```
public class NetService extends Service {

public static Client client = new Client("192.168.1.5");
Thread call;
BufferedWriter out;
int a;
String a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15;
public static int get = 5;
Intent intent2;

NotificationManager mNM;

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    NetService getService() {
        return NetService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    showNotification();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   a1 ="Hello everyone !!"

    new Thread(new Runnable(){


        public void run() {

            try {
                client.connectToServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                client.setstream();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            while(true){

            try {
                client.getFromServer();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



            try {
                client.sendToServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        }

    }).start();



    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    client.closeall();
    super.onDestroy();
}


private void showNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = ("remote_service_started");
    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.togon, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Connect.class), 0);
    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, ("remote_service_label"),
                   text, contentIntent);
    // Send the notification.
    // We use a string id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
    mNM.notify(R.string.remote_service_started, notification);
}}
```

UI activity :

```
    package com.bannob.shms;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.bannob.shms.NetService.LocalBinder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;




public class Main extends Activity {

    public static ViewFlipper vf, lightvf, secvf;
    private Float oldTouchValue;
    public static TextView tv1, lighttv, sectv, tvlight1, tvlight2, tvlight3, 
    tvlight4, gasactivetv, flameactivetv, mdetect1tv, automodtv, indoortv, hmdtv;
    public static LinearLayout wallpaper, fansbanner;
    public static ToggleButton envtog1, envtog2, envtog3, envtog4;
    public static Switch lights1, lights2, lights3, lights4;
    public static VideoView vview;
    public static ImageView safeiv1, safeiv2, seciv1, seciv2, secbubble, safebubble;
    Typeface tf;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    File file;
    File values;
    String[] valuesArray= new String[30];
    int a;
    String a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20;
    NetService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    /**********************************************************************/
    /* Look for the definitions of the previous declarations below !!!!   */
    /**********************************************************************/


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // reference to activity_main.Xml at layout Folder


        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById ()

        onStart();

        tv1.setText(mService.a1);







    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

}
```

second activity (which start the service):

```
package com.bannob.shms;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Connect extends Activity {

    EditText conet1;
    Button con ;
    public static Boolean state = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connect);

        con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.conb1);

        conet1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conet1);

        con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){          

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(state == false ){
                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NetService.class));
                state = true;
                con.setText("Disconnect");

                }
                else{
                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NetService.class));    
                state = false;  
                con.setText("Connect");
                }


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way 
 BroadCastReceiver & sendBroadcast

in you activities register a BroadcastReciver

```
IntentFilter    newFileReceiverfilter = new IntentFilter(App.INTENT_NEW_FILE_COMMING ) ;
        registerReceiver(newfileReceiver, newFileReceiverfilter);

        newfileReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent in) {
                                    Log.i("FileName", in.getStringExtra(IntentExtrasKeys.NF_FILE_NAME) + "");
                }
                }
```

in you Service broadCast an Intent with the data you want to send as Extra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(App.INTENT_NEW_FILE_COMMING);
     intent.putExtra(IntentExtrasKeys.NF_FILE_NAME, "img2.jpg" ) ;
     ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

to send more data to the service from the activities just send more Intents 
there is dirty way 
 u can let the service write it vaule in static class and read the static class from the activities